# django allauth facebook local development

Tags: django, facebook, django-allauth

I'm using [django-allauth](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth) for Facebook authentication in developement for a site and have set up accordingly:

within the facebook app settings on facebok:

```
Namespace: test_login
App Domains: blank
Site URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Canvas URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Secure Canvas URL: https://127.0.0.1:8000/
```

in Django admin I created new Social app:

```
Provider: Facebook
name: test_login
client_id: xxx
Secret: xxx
Sites: http://127.0.0.1:8000/
```

as you can see I added a new site `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` instead of `example.com`.

The SITE_ID in the settings.py is the correct one.

So everything should be working, but it's not. After clicking to login through Facebook I get

```
Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: 
One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. 
It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a 
subdomain of one of the App's domains.
```

What am I missing? What isn't configured? As far as I can understand I should be able to use `127.0.0.1:8000` for testing.

Comment: I haven't touched this in two days and now it just works. Long live facebook. Issue solved (on it's own).

Answer (score 10):

It worked for me setting the url in Facebook as **`localhost`** instead of 127.0.0.1. Also pass `localhost:8000` to `./manage.py runserver`

Comment: [In the docs](http://django-allauth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#facebook) "Development callback URL
Leave your App Domains empty and put in he section Website with Facebook Login put this as your Site URL: http://localhost:8000"

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem an hour ago. I've fixed it by setting the `Site URL` and `Valid OAuth redirect URIs` to `http://fuf.me:8080`. fuf.me point to 127.0.0.1, so your localhost, and also I've changed the default 8000 port to 8080. You can do this by running `python manage.py runserver localhost:8080`

Also I've enabled Browser OAuthLogin and WebOauthLogin.