# Django allauth & facebook: Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration

Tags: python, django, facebook, django-allauth

I successfully run the example from [The missing django-allauth tutorial](http://www.sarahhagstrom.com/2013/09/the-missing-django-allauth-tutorial/) to login with facebook, but now I have this error when I try to install django-allauth from scratch:

```
 Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration
```

In facebook, my site URL is set to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/`, this works for the example but not my app.
Where can the error come from?

---

I also don't understand the "sites" field in Django administration: Home › Socialaccount › Social apps › AppName. It is set to example.com by default, I don't know what to set here, although it works fine with example.com for the example...

---

Just for info, here is the example's main urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns(
    '',
    # prevent the extra are-you-sure-you-want-to-logout step on logout
    (r'^accounts/logout/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout', {'next_page': '/'}),

    url(r'^', include('larb.urls')),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

and urls.py for larb:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

from larb import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
     url(r'^$', views.index, name='index')
)
```

and my unique main urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
from Romanesco import settings

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',

    url(r'^$', 'draw.views.index'),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),

)
```

---

I have noticed a difference, in the example the facebook button links to `href="/accounts/facebook/login/"` ; whereas in the default login page (when it fails) it's `href="javascript:allauth.facebook.login('', 'authenticate', 'login')"`.

If I go to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/facebook/login/` manually it works!

Comment: I had the exact same problem, with the non-js link to FB login working but otherwise not.  It worked instantly when I changed the `Website URL` to `http://localhost:8000/`, and did `./manage.py runserver localhost:8000` as [this answer suggests](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19573422/3188213).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your browser, change `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` to `localhost:8000/`

That should fix the problem.

Still under platform website, change site URL to  `http://localhost:8000/`

Answer (score 4):

In parameter of your Facebook application ([https://developers.facebook.com/x/apps/**...**/settings/advanced/](https://developers.facebook.com/x/apps/.../settings/advanced/)) be sure to add a platform Website and add url: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/`
And after in advanced (still on parameter) put "Embedded browser OAuth Login" and "Client OAuth Login" on !

**EDIT**:

Ok so you need to add `http://127.0.0.1:8000` in your admin site and after you go on each social app and add localhost on site field and not to example.

Comment: "Embedded browser OAuth Login" was off, but it still does not work with the default link. And it still works with the link `http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/facebook/login/` added manually

Comment: Are u sure u create a plateform in facebbok app for link your app ?? Because the error corresponding to a bad configuration of facebook i think ....

Comment: yes, I added a Website, with URL `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` and it works with `http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/facebook/login/`.

Comment: I've tried it, it does not work (or I misunderstood...), but I'm fine with the static link solution.

Comment: Ok nice sorry for my english ;)

Comment: I didn't mean anything bad for your english, but maybe I misunderstood ;-) Maybe  NZP's solution will work, but I'm ok with the static link for now.

Comment: When I put http://127.0.0.1:8000/ in the site url on Facebook, I received "is not valid because it is not a Facebook url." I think they must have made some changes to it. I can only use localhost:8000 now.